# uconv on Mac OS X anywhere?

Tags: homebrew, unicode

Is the ***uconv*** utility (a tool from [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/home) that provides [Unicode normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence)) available for Mac OS X?

I did not find it in ***homebrew*** and searching the web for solutions did not turn out anything useful for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My solution for you:

`brew install icu4c`

Read the message after install (nothing is at this moment direct available ...):

> ==> Caveats, 
>   This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

`brew list icu4c | grep uconv`

> /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/55.1/bin/uconv
>
> /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/55.1/share/man/man1/uconv.1

And after all, here my example for using this tool for normalization (NFC) utf8 text:

`/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/55.1/bin/uconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -x NFC ~/Desktop/ue.txt |  od -t x1`

Comment: Nice.... but the hard-coded version '55.1' in your path won't work nowadays for the next guy who might simply c&p

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will suit your needs, but check out `iconv` which is coming with osx. Try `iconv --list` to list the supported encodings.

Comment: It looks like iconv only converts between character sets. Uconv converts text (unicode only) from one form to another equivalent form.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `man iconv` states "The iconv program converts text from one encoding to another encoding." `man uconv` says "uconv converts [...] from one encoding to another"

Comment: I am trying to convert to unicode's NFD (see above ref for Unicode normalization).

Comment: You may do so using `iconv -f <from_encoding> -t UTF-8-MAC <input>`. Note that the `utf-8-mac` character set stands for unicode's NFD

Comment: Thanks!! This prompts two more questions: Can iconv also converts to Unicode NFC? And where is it documented that UTF-8-MAC stands for NFD?

Comment: Yes, it can. Use `UTF-8` for unicode's NFC. I found out using google, leading me to [this](http://serverfault.com/a/427200). Not sure where it's documented.

Comment: `utf-8-mac` is not NFD but a [variant of NFD used by HFS+](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1235/_index.html) where certain ranges of characters are not decomposed. `printf \\uf900|/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin/uconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -x NFD|xxd -p` prints `e8b188` (which is decomposed) but `printf \\uf900|iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8-mac|xxd -p` prints `efa480` (which is not decomposed).