# Error while installing PostgreSQL 12.9 on Apple Silicon (M1 Max) via asdf

Tags: apple-silicon, postgresql

I'm trying to install PostgreSQL via [`asdf-postgres`](https://github.com/smashedtoatoms/asdf-postgres) plugin by running `asdf install postgres 12.9` on 2021 MacBook Pro (with M1 Max, running Monterey 12.0.1) but getting the following error:

```
100   190  100   190    0     0    345      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   346
/Users/kushal/.asdf/plugins/postgres/bin/install: line 45: uconv: command not found
Building with options: --prefix=/Users/kushal/.asdf/installs/postgres/12.9     --with-uuid=e2fs     --with-openssl     --with-zlib     --with-libraries=/opt/local/lib:/sw/lib:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib:/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib     --with-includes=/opt/local/lib:/sw/lib:/usr/local/opt/openssl/include:/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/include:/opt/homebrew/include:/usr/local/include:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib --with-uuid=e2fs --with-openssl --with-libraries=/usr/local/lib:/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib --with-includes=/usr/local/include:/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `arm64-apple-darwin21.1.0': machine `arm64-apple' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/sh config/config.sub arm64-apple-darwin21.1.0 failed
```

Please note that I'm trying to install it against OpenSSL 1.1 (which is installed via Homebrew already). Also, I'm exported `POSTGRES_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS` in my `zshrc` as:

```
export POSTGRES_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS="--with-uuid=e2fs --with-openssl --with-libraries=/usr/local/lib:/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib --with-includes=/usr/local/include:/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
```

I believe Postgres is already supported on Apple Silicon, am I missing something here?

Comment: The error implies that M1 isn’t supported/known to the installer. What does the Postgres website say? Did you try to install via Homebrew as well?

Comment: @nohillside Yes it installs fine with Homebrew, so M1 is supported as far as postgres is concerned, however, project I work one manages all dependencies via `asdf` and this failing only with `asdf` is odd.

Comment: If you are using openSSL from Homebrew then you are NOT "manages all dependencies via asdf" If that is your project's requirement then you need to install openSSL with asdf otherwise just use Homebrew

Answer (score 2):

The error is as in the first line and the error is in asdf (wrapped so can read without scrolling):

> /Users/kushal/.asdf/plugins/postgres/bin/install: line 45: uconv: command not found

Looking at line 45 in the install script

```
  local icu_uconv=$(uconv -V)
```

Now uconv is not installed as part of macOS (Big Sur at least) Also see [uconv on Mac OS X anywhere?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/201590/237)

uconv is part of [ICU4C](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu4c/).

So you need to install ICU4C by asdf as that is your package manager.